# Serialize javascript object to json

Tags: javascript, json

I m trying to serialize java script object to json. Here is my code so far:

```
var info = {};

...

$.each(data, function (key, value) {
           info["name"] = value.name;
            info["id"] = value.id;
                        });
...

console.log(JSON.stringify(info));
```

But this returns me : `{}`

It would be grateful if some one can suggest me a way to get the out-put like below :

```
[{name: "John", id: "1"},
 {name: "Anna", id: "2"},
 {name: "Peter", id: "3"}]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- Change your `info` variable to an array, rather than a JSON object.

Change your code to:

```
var info = [];

$.each(data, function (key, value) {
         info.push({
             name: value.name,
             id: value.id
         });
});
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the quick reply and it works fine as well. :)